# pack in small circles into a bigger circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I'm trying to figure out a way to pack in smaller circles into a bigger one , but for some reason smaller circles are not correctly aligned.

I believe it's the position calculation that is probably missing something.

Please see the code for more details:

```js
var c_el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c_el.getContext("2d");

var canvas_width = c_el.clientWidth;
var canvas_height = c_el.clientHeight;
var circle1 = {
 r: 50, /// radius 
 pos: {
  x: (canvas_width / 2),
  y: (canvas_height / 2)
 }
}

var circle2 = {
 r: 5,
 pos:{}
}

var c2h = circle2.r * 2; /// circle height ////
var c2w = c2h; //// circle width /////

var c1h = circle1.r * 2; /// circle height ////
var c1w = c1h; //// circle width /////

var max_circles2_H = c1h / c2h; 

var r = circle1.r;
var d = circle1.r - 2;  //// segement distance from center ////

drawCircle( circle1 );
for(var col = 1; col < max_circles2_H; col++){
 var d = circle1.r - ( col * c2h); /// distance from center to segment ///
 var c = 2 * (Math.sqrt((r*r) - (d * d))); //// circle's chord length
 var max_circles2_W = c / c2w;
 for(var row = 1; row < max_circles2_W; row++){
  circle2.pos.x = (row * c2w) + (circle1.pos.x - circle1.r);
  circle2.pos.y = (col * c2h) + (circle1.pos.y - circle1.r);
  drawCircle(circle2);
 }
}


function drawCircle( circle ){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(circle.pos.x, circle.pos.y, circle.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain "to what" you need to align?

Comment: it's just that the overall shape of all those small circles should be similar to the bigger one..

Comment: So you want to not show the outside of this bigger circle?... big circle is "a window/the hole"?

Comment: I'm just trying to fit in all the `circle2` objects into `circle1`, that's all ...

Comment: This is a fun bit of maths! Do you want the small circles aligned in rows and columns like you have currently or could they be packed more efficiently if there is room? For example, you have nine small circles across the diameter when there is room to have ten.

Comment: See these examples of different ways the circles can be packed: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pack+circles+of+radius+5+in+a+circle+of+radius+50 I wouldn't attempt the densest packing method, but the hexagonal one is certainly achievable without too many changes to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close but it's needs a little adjusting.  You can see where x_offset is calculated and try some different math to tighten it up.

*update*
Added Math.ceil to max_circles2_W and it seems to fit.

```js
var c_el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c_el.getContext("2d");

var canvas_width = c_el.clientWidth;
var canvas_height = c_el.clientHeight;
var circle1 = {
 r: 50, /// radius 
 pos: {
  x: (canvas_width / 2),
  y: (canvas_height / 2)
 }
}

var circle2 = {
 r: 5,
 pos:{}
}

var c2h = circle2.r * 2; /// circle height ////
var c2w = c2h; //// circle width /////

var c1h = circle1.r * 2; /// circle height ////
var c1w = c1h; //// circle width /////

var max_circles2_H = c1h / c2h; 

var r = circle1.r;
var d = circle1.r - 2;  //// segement distance from center ////

drawCircle( circle1 );
for(var col = 1; col < max_circles2_H; col++){
 var d = circle1.r - ( col * c2h); /// distance from center to segment ///
 var c = 2 * (Math.sqrt((r*r) - (d * d))); //// circle's chord length
 var max_circles2_W = Math.ceil(c / c2w);
  
    // CALCULATE OFFSET HERE
    var x_offset = Math.floor((c1w - (max_circles2_W * c2w)) / 2);
  
 for(var row = 1; row < max_circles2_W; row++){
  circle2.pos.x = (row * c2w) + (circle1.pos.x - circle1.r) + x_offset;
  circle2.pos.y = (col * c2h) + (circle1.pos.y - circle1.r);
        ctx.fillText(row, circle2.pos.x-3, circle2.pos.y+4);
  drawCircle(circle2);
 }
}


function drawCircle( circle ){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(circle.pos.x, circle.pos.y, circle.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted to achieve, thanks alot ! :]